# Issues importing data-tier application to Azure SQL server

Tags: import, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am trying to import a .bacpac of a local sql database to my Azure SQL Server using SSMS, but it fails with the message

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The login already has an account under a different user name.
>   Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   CREATE USER [abc] FOR LOGIN [abc];

As far as I am aware, the login I am using is the server admin account and is the only account on the server. Is the problem created by the fact that I have a user in the database with the same name at the server admin account? Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please change the owner on the database on-premises to “sa” and generate the bacpac again?

My recommendation is to use Data Migration Assistant instead of importing a bacpac. It is the easiest way to migrate databases to Azure SQL Database. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).

Comment: Tried to do what you suggest, but Migration Assistant won't connect to my Azure server, saying "There are validation errors in the target server." I am using SQL authentication and giving the server admin username and password.

Comment: Ok, got it to connect but in step 2 of deploy results it fails to create the sa user because `The login already has an account under a different user name.`

Comment: How was I supposed to change the owner on the database to sa - I just renamed the owner account. Was that wrong?

Comment: Change the owner to another login instead of sa

Comment: If I right-click on the database in SSMS and look at the properties the owner is listed as my Windows user, if I look in the security folder of the database at the sa user it is listed as owning the db_owner schema (which I thought made it the database owner). Not sure which to change or how to do it. Sorry for my ignorance. EDIT: I just worked out how to change the owner of the db_owner schema, which I've done. Will try again to migrate.

Comment: Create a SQL Login instead and assign it as owner.

Comment: Well, the user sa still couldn't be created, but as it is no longer the owner, I went ahead with the migration, then uploaded my updated code and connected it to the database ok and my site works! Thank you Alberto.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Adding a SQL Server Active Directory Admin (temp), and logging in with that account also helped.